# I am creating QR code reader from pyboof module

Tags: python, java, python-3.x, object-detection, qr-code

**python**
As you can see i wrote the code of qrreader using pyboof module,
'print(pb.QrCodeDetector.detect(image='img1_main.png'))' I got an error in this line.
The detect function takes 2 arguments so, I passed the image only and I got self argument error. What will be the next argument? Please! help me to find this.

**error**
TypeError: QrCodeDetector.detect() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

```
import numpy as np
import pyboof as pb


print(pb.QrCodeDetector.detect(image='img1_main.png'))
```

Comment: You need to create an instance of QrCodeDetector. Try adding `()` after it to instantiate it before calling detect on it.

Comment: @user16320675 PyBoof is a Python wrapper for the computer vision library BoofCV. This is a Java library

Comment: @Adid- I tried what you said but it's giving an **error** -Traceback (most recent call last): File "F:\INTERNSHIP\NewQRcodeReader\test2.py", line 10, in <module> ob = pb.QrCodeDetector() TypeError: QrCodeDetector.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument:

Comment: What do I pass in this class brackets 'pb.QrCodeDetector()'?                                 if I do not pass any argument in these brackets so it gives an error which I have mentioned above.                                                                                                
'ob = pb.QrCodeDetector()
print(ob.detect(image))'

Comment: [Example from PyBoof](https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/PyBoof/blob/SNAPSHOT/examples/qrcode_detect.py)